# Correct way to do error reporting in Java?

Tags: java

I am building a simple interpreter and there are many areas that could fail.

For example, invalid identifier, invalid opcode, etc.

I would like it so that these errors can be kept in an array and then I can feed it to some sort of output stream later.

The simple way  have thought of doing this is to create an error object that I pass to my source code loader, parser, interpreter, etc and they add errors as they find them.

If at any point, any of those objects find an error, I grab the errors and do not continue onto the next class. For example, if parsing fails, don't bother running the interpreter.

Is this an appropriate way to go about this or is there a better way I am not thinking of (Exceptions?), Error interfaces?

It is a command line application.

Thanks

Comment: Does this application have a GUI or is it command line?

Comment: You are indeed correct. Exceptions are not a good candidate here (since having a parse error is not really an exceptional case). Passing an error queue around and pushing to it until you fail is the correct approach here. Also, command line vs. GUI is completely irrelevant.

Comment: There are probably a dozen different ways to do this.  Fundamentally you need a list, and probably some concept of error severity, so you know when to simply quit.  Lots of choices as to how you structure it, and no real "standards" in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has a notion of status.

IStatus interface has a severity code, and message.
MultiStatus implements composite pattern.
Custom descendant define additional fields to represent different kind of messages in their specific form.
Usually a method returns IStatus composed from the return values of its callees.

Resulting hirrarhical structure is pretty convenient to view in both interactive GUI and console.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good approach. Define a class with various error flags (these may be booleans or even counters or maps of counters depending on severity), collect errors as you work and then check at specific points if the accumulated problems warrant bailout.

I have done it this way myself a few times. Additionally, a list collecting explicit error message texts can be useful. In that way, all the problems detected can be dumped to the user at the end for easier comprehension. The program would say "I will now stop because there were 5 errors and 20 warnings... accumulated text follows ..." I have had a "Story" class, basically a list of formattable stuff, in use for some time for just that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that you came up with seems very similar to the one used in [spring validation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html). Some accumulator [`Errors`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html) object that is passed around to all the [`Validator`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html)s and gathers all the encountered errors.

Although this looks quite fine for a validation framework, in your case I would argue it's a bit unnatural to add an error carrier to all your method signatures. If you do need a carrier to pass to indefinite chains, consider keeping its lifecycle within each step.

Since you have precise checkpoints and you'll never get to the next stage once errors are encountered in the current one, why not just return some `Result` object from each processing step ?

This result will hold the entire list of errors (if "unsuccessful"), but it will be instantiated and populated within the specific step and then returned to the caller (in case anyone cares). You can also have specific subclasses (like `LoadResult`, `ParseResult` etc.) with specific data and metadata for each step.